# floats not stacking beneath eachother

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-post-type

Using Post Type Builder, I created a CPT called Concerts. On a clean install of the theme on my server, I produced this result, which is structurally correct: https://plushdesign.net/plush8/concert/deck-the-hall/

Each component is set in a unique div within a parent div, and they should all be floating to the right of the photo. The divs are all set to float left.

When I moved the CPT/css over to the development site, the same css displays this: http://spiderman.ephronsystems.com/concert/san-francisco-symphony-presents-deck-the-hall/

How to get the purple button to float down below the details, and the text to wrap beneath it (it will not wrap around the photo, which is the desired behavior). I tried every combination of clearing and display properties but it is very stubborn.

Here is the relevant html:

```
div class="ptb_items_wrapper entry-content" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemscope="">
<div class="ptb_first_row ptb_row ptb_concert_row ">
<div class="ptb_col ptb_col1-1 ptb_col_first">
<div class="ptb_module ptb_thumbnail ptb_module_inline">
<div class="title ptb_module ptb_title">
<div class="details ptb_module ptb_text ptb_details">
<div class="purchasetickets ptb_module ptb_text ptb_purchase_tickets">
<div class="description ptb_module ptb_text ptb_description">
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant css:

```
div.ptb_items_wrapper.entry-content {float:left;overflow:auto;padding-top:2em;border-top:1px solid #ededed;}
div.ptb_module.ptb_thumbnail.ptb_module_inline {float:left;margin-right: 1em;}
div.title.ptb_module.ptb_title {float:left;}
div.details.ptb_module.ptb_text.ptb_details {float:left;/*margin-right: 200px;*/}

div.purchasetickets.ptb_module.ptb_text.ptb_purchase_tickets {float:left;color:#fff !important;}
.purchasetickets { padding: 6px 16px; background: #872c8c;margin:3px 0 12px !important;border-radius: 1.2em;font-size: 14px;text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: 2px;color:#fff !important;}
a.purchasetickets, .ptb_purchase_tickets a {color:#fff !important;}
.purchasetickets:hover {opacity:.5;}

div.description.ptb_module.ptb_text.ptb_description {float:left;}
```

thanks!

Comment: Speaking of *"super obvious"*, have you considered reading [ask]?

Comment: [SO] is not about other people helping you. It's about you helping other people. To do this, you must make sure your question will help other people with the same issue find the solution faster. But when you fix your issue on the linked site, your question here will lose relevance. So please, before anything else, create a [mcve]. Also use appropriate tags: `wordpress` and `custom-post-type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the new CSS:

```
div.ptb_items_wrapper.entry-content {float:left;overflow:auto;padding-top:2em;border-top:1px solid #ededed;}
div.ptb_module.ptb_thumbnail.ptb_module_inline {float:left;margin-right: 1em;}
div.title.ptb_module.ptb_title {}
div.details.ptb_module.ptb_text.ptb_details {/*margin-right: 200px;*/}

div.purchasetickets.ptb_module.ptb_text.ptb_purchase_tickets {color:#fff !important;display: inline-block;}
    .purchasetickets { padding: 6px 16px; background: #872c8c;margin:3px 0 12px !important;border-radius: 1.2em;font-size: 14px;text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: 2px;color:#fff !important;}
    a.purchasetickets, .ptb_purchase_tickets a {color:#fff !important;}
    .purchasetickets:hover {opacity:.5;}

div.description.ptb_module.ptb_text.ptb_description {float:left;}
```

Summary change:

- Only float the image
- Apply `display: inline-block` on the button.

Also, to help others, please add the appropriate tags to your question, as mentioned by @Andrei Gheorghiu. :)

Comment: Thanks, Chris Happy. Why did the floats work in my first example but not in my second (which worked using your code edit, though I took the float off the description as I didn't want it to clear the rest of the text/image).

Comment: I don't think you used the same code in the first one. It seems to be commented out.